# Convert array object to object with same key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I have an array of objects, for each element inside the array contains the same field as `roleMapping`. I want to find all elements with the same key combined into an array. Below is the list of object array that I want to convert

```js
a = [
  {
    roleMapping: {
      123: {
        shortName: "1",
        name: "2"
      },
      234: {
        shortName: "123",
        name: "123"
      },
    } 
  },
  {
    roleMapping: {
      123: {
        shortName: "3",
        name: "4"
      }
    } 
  },
  {
    roleMapping: {
      234: {
        shortName: "3",
        name: "4"
      }
    } 
  }
]
```

I want to result:

```js
a = {
    123: [
        {
                shortName: "1",
                name: "2"
        },
        {
                shortName: "3",
                name: "4"
        }
    ],
    234 : [
        {
                shortName: "123"
                name: "123"
        },
        {
                shortName: "3",
                name: "4"
        }
    ]
}
```

The purpose I use this is so that when I want to access the `shortName`, I rely on the key of the object to find the value to use.

Comment: can you please post what you have tried from your side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with reduce

```js
const a = [
  {
    roleMapping: {
      123: {
        shortName: "1",
        name: "2"
      },
      234: {
        shortName: "123",
        name: "123"
      },
    } 
  },
  {
    roleMapping: {
      123: {
        shortName: "3",
        name: "4"
      }
    } 
  },
  {
    roleMapping: {
      234: {
        shortName: "3",
        name: "4"
      }
    } 
  }
]

const b = a.reduce((acc,{roleMapping}) => {
  Object.entries(roleMapping).forEach(([k,v]) => (acc[k]??=[]).push(v))
  return acc
},{})

console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `convert` in the following code snippet does the required job:

```
function convert (a) {
  let b = {};
  for (let { roleMapping } of a) {
    for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(roleMapping)) {
      (b[k] || (b[k] = [])).push(v);
    }
  }
  return b;
}
```